# Copying data files upon build in Java/Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Along with my java source, I have some data files that I would like to copy to the build dir when the source is build. Currently I am not using any build tools (e.g. maven or ant), but develop and run unit tests solely from within Eclipse.
Can I somehow ask Eclipse to copy these data files when it builds my java code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First Create a new source folder call it something like res, you can use this folder to store your data files. Next open the *Java Build Path* section of the project properties (from the context menu of the project). Select the *Source* tab. In this tab you can control the output folders of each of the source folders. By default eclipse copies all the non-java files int the source folder to output directory during the build.

Comment: by any chance, do you know how the same can be done in a C++ project? I created a file in a source folder, and it seems like it isnt copied by default. Also I cannot find the "Java Build Path" equivalent in the properties of the C++ project

Answer (score 3):

Go with Ant. To be honest this is the best solution for automation of app building process.

I am not using Eclipse often. But I bet there must be a build file (build.xml) where you can add something like the code below to it and have it always executed when building your app.

This is how I am doing it in my build file for one of my projects. I am copying here two folders with all their content to a dist (which in NetBeans serves as a distribution folder where application jar is being created), so then I can easily run my application externally outside the IDE.

Be aware that the target name in Eclipse might differ. But you should find a correct one described in the build file probably.

```
 

<!-- to copy data & images folders' contents to dist folder on build. -->
    <target name="-post-jar" description="Copying Images">
        <property name="images.dir" value="${dist.dir}/images" />
        <property name="data.dir" value="${dist.dir}/data" />

        <copy todir="${images.dir}">
            <fileset dir="./images" />
        </copy>
        <echo level="info" message="Images folder content was copied."/>

        <copy todir="${data.dir}">
            <fileset dir="./data" />
        </copy>
        <echo level="info" message="Data folder content was copied."/>
    </target>
```

All the best, Boro.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will start using Ant in the near feature. Seems far more flexible than plain-Eclipse. Nice and informative answer!

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse isn't really meant to copy things around (it may have that feature and I don't know about it). Like you alluded to, that's a job for Maven or Ant. However, for your JUnit tests, you have a couple of options...

- Open the data files based on a project relative path.
- Use [getResourceAsStream(filename)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) and add the data files to the build-path