# Use project's own .java files as resource files

Tags: java, eclipse, resources

I have made a small program in Java that displays its .java source with a gui. It does not use FileChooser to do this. I am reading the .java sources with the aid of following statements

```
String resName = "/dev/classes/"+name+".java"
Scanner s = new Scanner(FilePrinter.class.getResourceAsStream(resName));
```

where `name` is the name of the .java file i.e. if the file is `MyProg.java` then `name==Myprog`. Of course my program is inside the `dev.classes` package

The thing is that when I export my project to JAR and include source files this works because source files reside inside the `/dev/classes/` directory.

However, I haven't yet discovered a way to make my program run in **Eclipse** or from the command line without giving me exception.

And of course when someone tries to add those source files to be used automatically as resource files the process fails.

Can I somehow use the same code both when running from Eclipse and from the JAR? It must be something very trivial but because I am not Java expert I cannot see.

Comment: It is just a matter of ensuring the source is inside the Jar that Eclipse makes.  If it is, it will work.

Comment: Thank you @andrew-thompson. I have ensured it and it works inside the jar but not when running directly from Eclipse. And as you can understand it is not like a regular let's say .txt file. The .java files are not copied by Eclipse to the /bin/ directory!

Comment: *"it is not like a regular let's say .txt file."* A Java source is usually a particular encoding and the extension is different, and while it will have 'Java code' inside it, it is very much like a text file to a computer (or software).

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607723/copying-data-files-upon-build-in-java-eclipse

Comment: @jschoen  I think it is very much on-topic.  Good call.  +1

Comment: @Andrew Thompson No doubt about that. What I meant is that whereas if you create a .txt file inside a package this is treated as _resource_ and will be copied to the `/bin` directory. However, how can you use you own .java files as resources, inside Eclipse? Within the .jar it works though...

Comment: @YannisP.  Not sure, but confident that playing with the defaults of eclipse (I think you can choose to have source & class in the same path) or writing an Ant build file should do it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @AndrewThompson and jschoen. I have actually followed Andrew's path. See edit for the details

Comment: Please enter the edit as an answer and (when you can) accept it.  Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it. Actually you either have to use Ant or Maven. However, this can be done in Eclipse as well as follows:

On the Eclipse Project Properties>Java Build Path you can choose on the bottom Default Output folder: `<your_project_name>/src`.

This causes class files be compiled in the same directory as the .java files and finally does what I wanted.

Thanks to @AndrewThompson for suggesting to try this